# What is the name of the browser in InAppBrowser?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

We're using Phonegap InAppBrowser to point to our website.  On our website we are checking that users are only using a select group of browsers and show a warning if the user isn't using one of them.  We'd like to add inappbrowser to the group of acceptable browsers but what is it's actual name?  'inappbrowser' does not seem to work.

Comment: If you just echo cgi.HTTP_USER_AGENT, what do you see? I believe it will be the same as the system browser.

Comment: You could open it to: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

Comment: I just tested w/ an Android 4.4.4 system and got this: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Google Nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920 Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: @RaymondCamden - you want to list this as answer?  It's correct and I could accept it.

Comment: Adding now. (more text for a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user agent should be the same as the system web view, but you can confirm by hitting a page that echoes the HTTP_USER_AGENT cgi variable. A good example of this is whatsmyuseragent.com.